# Detect a certain point of image progromatically

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have been studying how this [link](http://www.monicavinader.com/necklace-designer/C-300) creates a custom products. The part that confuses me is that whenever you add a necklace with different length, the pendant will still be centered at the end of that necklace. The following image shows where they always place the pendant.

[image: the place where pendant is placed]

here is a my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfn4rzzz/). I realized that pendant's styles `top` and `left` changes whenever the necklace changes, so somehow they detect the endpoint of the necklace and calculate the top and left of the pendant and place the pendant there.

Therefore, is it possible to detect the pointed area progromatically using either PHP or jQuery image processing? if not, what is the technique used to place the pendant on the right place.

Comment: I'd imagine the apex of the bend is hard coded co-ordinates based on the selected chain.

Comment: Yes, those coordinates are stored in the database, along with the path to the image of the necklace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle

here is the link [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/nfn4rzzz/1/)